# Java large file AES Encryption is very slow

Tags: java, spring, encryption, aes, aescryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to encrypt a 512 Mb file with AES/CBC algorithm. It is taking around 7 sec which is too much. How to reduce the encryption time and make it faster.

I'm using a fixed key and tried using CipherOutStream as well as cipher.update() instead of cipher.dofinal(). Still, it is taking around 7 secs.

How much time generally it would take to encrypt a 512 MB file with the below encryption. It is taking 6 seconds for me on a Mac with 16 GB memory and 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 processor. I'm using JDK 11 for execution. Is it normal or my code is responding slow. Should I be concerned? How to improve the time for encryption.

```
package com.file.encrypterdecrypter;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "aesencryptionKey";
    private static final String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        File inputFile = new ClassPathResource("fivetwelvemb.zip").getFile();
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        SecretKeySpec secretkey = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");


        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        OutputStream encryptStream = encryptDecryptBinary(inputStream, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Encryption Time in ms : " + (endTime - startTime));

    }

    public static OutputStream encryptDecryptBinary(InputStream inputStream, int encryptMode, SecretKeySpec secretkey) throws Exception {
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        aesCipher.init(encryptMode, secretkey);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("temp.zip");
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        aesCipher.init(encryptMode, secretkey);
        CipherOutputStream cipherStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, aesCipher);

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = inputStream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            cipherOutputStream.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        cipherOutputStream.close();
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably becasue of `inputStream.readAllBytes()`(no cached read data). Just like that `buf` you write bunch-by-bunch, do the same for reading file.

Comment: Try the `ByteBuffer` version of the encryption API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal-java.nio.ByteBuffer-java.nio.ByteBuffer-.  It'll at least spare the time for reading/writing all the bytes.

Comment: @911992 Sorry, I commented that line. Edited my post.

Comment: What if you write to a file rather on mem `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: Same response time if I write to File or BufferedByteStream.

Comment: Don't use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You don't need all the data in memory at once. Put a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStream`, and a `BufferedInputStream` around the `FileInputStream`. Don't forget to close the input stream.

Comment: I tried with BufferedInputStream and writing to BufferedOutputStream wrapped around the file stream, it is still the same time around 6 seconds. @MarquisofLorne

Comment: Every command-line AES encryption program I’ve tried takes just as long.  But you definitely should not read the entire file into a ByteArrayOutputStream;  that is certain to make the task slower.  The whole point of an InputStream is that you can read small portions of the data and process them, to avoid taking up substantial amounts of memory.

Comment: As we are talking about really large files you maybe shift the reading of that file from "FileInputStream" to a "MemoryMappedFile" combined with "MappedByteBuffer". According to the benchmark on http://sherxon.com/blog/fastest-io-in-java (code available on GitHub) this combination is much faster than any other readings. Unfortunately I found nowhere any working implementation for an AES based file encryption so I cannot show any example.